# Export order from remote server

Tags: orders, magento-1, sales-order, export

I need to export order form magento with remote scripts.

When I work in local I use:

```
require_once("/app/Mage.php");

Mage::init();

// Set an Admin Session
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));

$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(1);
$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$session->setUser($userModel);
$session->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());

$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');


// extract order

$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                            ->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach($collection as $order)
{
$billingStreet = $billingAddress->getStreet();
[...]
}
```

But if I want to connect from remote server?

I cannot find an example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using some custom scripts like this, especially if you want to do it from remote server, **I suggest you use the Magento SOAP API (or REST or XMLRpc depending on your needs).**

Here's the API documentation for the Sales Order : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/salesOrder.html

And here's the introduction to the API: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html